# Unable to add Tester Email Address to Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am unable to add new Testers Email, in Google play Console. In my Application , I have a list called `Beta Review Team` ,Under that I have a list of emails for test users. It has worked for the past few years. I have Currently 84 testers. (Find screenshot 2)

I need to add one new email to this list. Is there any limitations for test users?
Can anyone please help me?

[image][image]

Answer (score 58):

Press ENTER after you filled the emails to the textbox. I discovered it after I got emotional ("do you want an Enter little **** or what?")

Comment: You're a life saver. I spent hours for this...

Comment: This should be fixed through google, how do we should know that ENTER should be pressed !!! Thank you though for your answer

Comment: Thanks so much for this, and WTF Google???

Comment: Unbelievable mate. Took me one freaking day to get to your answer and finally... Google is dumb.

Answer (score 20):

When adding an email address to a tester list, one limitation is the email must be linked to a Google account. This is easy to forget when adding co-workers that have corporate email addresses.

Comment: This can be a cause of the "This email address doesn't exist" error message. Some users have multiple email addresses and a different account may be linked to their Google Play account.

Answer (score 18):

I was getting an error ("This email address doesn't exist") when trying to add a new email to my email list.

I figured out that I can only add as tester an email that was previously added to my Google Developer account under "Users and permissions". So after I added that email there and the person accepts the invitation to join my account, then I was able to add it with success to my test email list.

Comment: I was able to add users with accounts other than Google using this method.

Comment: I don't think this is true. You should be able to add emails to an email list without them being in "Users and permissions". AFAIK Users and Permissions is meant for giving people access to your Play Console developer account, but I could be wrong.

Comment: ["This email address doesn't exist" can occur when the email address isn't actually linked to a Google Play account.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085024/unable-to-add-tester-email-address-to-google-play-console/68535472#comment135964865_68535472) I think this is a better thing to check first.

Answer (score 2):

I was also unable to edit my email list when I tried to enter them manually/using the text field (the 'Save changes' button remained greyed out).

However, when I uploaded a csv file containing the email addresses (via the 'Upload CSV file' button), it worked and I was able to update the email list this way.

Answer (score 1):

Enter email, press enter then save should jump to blue at the bottom right.

Comment: This seems "Thanks" for the existing and highly upvoted answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66507995/7733418 If you cannot make more obvious what additional insight you contribute the only way to avoid the unpleasant impression that you are trying for some reputation by copying existing solutions. Please take the [tour].

Comment: What a terrible UX from Google.